# Link to tags from page with Pelican

Tags: hyperlink, pelican

I am using the [Pelican static site generator](http://blog.getpelican.com/).  According to the [documentation](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.4.0/content.html#linking-to-internal-content), it is possible to link to tags using the syntax `{tag}tagname`.

This works fine when linking from a blog article.  However, if I link from a [page](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.4.0/content.html#pages), the link it generates will be to `/pages/tag/tagname.html`, which is incorrect.  It should be `/tag/tagname.html`.

What is the correct way of linking to the list of articles under a certain tag, from a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may report this as a bug.

However you can link to a tag's page using the following syntax:

```
`link text <../tag/tag_name.html>`_
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm doing currently.  Thanks for confirming that I didn't miss any obvious ways.